# Load menu via SceneManager

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine, load

I'd like to know if it's a good or bad idea to load the main menu, options and other GUI-stuff via the SceneManager's async-method (additive) into my game (Unity3D).

The idea behind is that the game might not need so much memory if I load all of the GUI (main menu, options, level selection, achievements, etc.) asynchronously (additive) in my game.

This is some code I found but it doesn't work:

```
bool  transitionIsDone;  // set elsewhere when the camera finishes moving

IEnumerator loadNextScene()
{
    string name = "ALegitSceneName";
    AsyncOperation _async = new AsyncOperation();
    _async = SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(name, LoadSceneMode.Additive);
    _async.allowSceneActivation = false;

    while(!transitionIsDone)
    {
        yield return null;
    }

    _async.allowSceneActivation = true;

    while (!_async.isDone) 
    {
        yield return null;
    }

    Scene nextScene = SceneManager.GetSceneByName(name);
    if (nextScene.IsValid()) 
    {
        SceneManager.SetActiveScene(nextScene);
        SceneManager.UnloadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name);
    }
}
```

Comment: what is `transitionIsDone`? and what does `but it doesn't work:` mean exactly? And what are your concerns .. in general why not load the menu scene and unload it when done (this is just not really what your code block is about ...)

Comment: transitionIsDone is a bool.

Comment: I can see that .. but where does it come from?

Comment: I updated the code.